# JwtBearerAuthentication doesnt return 403 Forbidden, always returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

If ClaimsIdentity set through JwtBearerAuthentication middleware doesnt have enough roles required through

```
[Authorize(Roles="whateverrole")]
```

it returns 401 instead of 403.

I am struggling with this in asp.net core web api whole night. I have also seen this question on stackoverflow but i havent seen any solution i could make work. The order of registering middleware nor AutomaticChallange setting did the job.

I dont know if i am missing something but it seems shocking that this hasn't been solved properly for years. It is so annoying.

Is there any normal, usual, non-workaround, non-hack way of solving this?

**UPDATE (in response to comment from @juunas)**

I have tried that and roles are mapped correctly from Claims.
So, if i remove Roles requirement from attribute, for all roles that user is assigned to (in JWT token) User.IsInRole(x) returns true. So mapping works just fine.

About moving from roles based authorization to policies...can you provide some some link with some best practices, recommendations or something that you base that statement on?
I am not saying its not something to be done but would just like to understand it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the role requirement and seeing if `User.IsInRole("whateverrole")` returns true? In ASP.NET Core you should try to move away from the role-based authorization as you have to actually define to the middleware what claim it should consider as roles. It's easier to just make a policy that requires the presence of that claim and specify the policy name to AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've answered to it in question UPDATE.

Comment: Well, the official ASP.NET Core documentation is pretty good for understanding how authorization can be done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

Comment: yes ok, but i still dont see how you get to return 403. can you please point me to something mentioning that? tnx

Comment: That is actually very odd, and I am not quite sure why it is happening.

Comment: I was hoping that this would be fixed in .Net Core :(. Why 401 when you are actually authenticated??? It should be 403! Or is there any specific reason why they have kept so which I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the difference in these to errors to understand why you will get one and not the other.

401 is for authentication.  If you are getting this error then you have to ask yourself is the user logged in, or does the user have a current token provided by a valid token provider?  If the token has expired or the provider is not valid then you can get a 401.  If this is what you are getting then you need to check User.Identity.IsAuthenticated does this return true?  Most likely it returns false.

403 is for authorization.  This would mean the user has a valid token, but the token they have does not give them access to the resource they are requesting.  This is where you would want to check User.IsInRole() and it would return false.

If you're getting 401 it means that the user hasn't been authenticated i.e. they have not logged in, their login was invalid, the token has expired... etc.  As far as your application is concerned the user hasn't proved they are who they say they are yet.

Edit: Apologies for assuming the user wasn't Authenicated, I didn't see where you stated that they where in your first post.  It's hard to help without seeing code but my next guess is that the Claims check hasn't been added to the services pipeline.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("whateverrole", policy => policy.RequireClaim("whateverrole"));
  });
}
```

This is in your Startup.cs.  MS doc is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

Last update:  Simply put using the default Authorize attribute tag you can't change it.  MS designs I this way due to the number of layers in the pipeline that could impact authentication.  I was unaware of this because I use a custom Authorize attribute and forgot that I over wrote the way it handled status codes.

However I found a nice solution that might suite your needs https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/872#issuecomment-232624106

It adds an error page to the pipeline prior to the app.UseMvc() that redirects authentication errors to an error page that returns the correct status code.

Comment: i don't like to downvote. i'll just explain here: that is exactly the problem that user IsAuthenticated=true but since user don't have sufficient roles, he cannot pass Authorization. Thus, its 403 that should be returned. But its not, its 401 that's being returned. And that's obviously wrong.

Comment: ok, that is also a good example. have you tried that code? i have tested policies also and it still returns 401 instead of 403. what does it return on your side if user don't have 'whateverrole' claim?

Comment: yes, but there are recommendations from asp.net core security team not to use custom Authorize attributes. also, an error page is not an option for web api, for example. i might be missing something important, but as far as i can tell, i just cannot believe this confusion happening. and it happens for years. its pre .net core thing.

Comment: its here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs

in HandleUnauthorized method, Response.StatusCode = 401

Comment: seems like custom Authorize attribute is the only way to go for now. Although, clearly not encouriged by asp.net core team. But i see no better solution for now.
Could you please provide your example of custom Authorize attribute? tnx